# NANT registry import

Tags: nant, regedit

I have a build task in CruiseControl.NET that needs to import a registry setting.  I have tried using the EXEC task and running regedit.exe but it seems to fail.

There doesn't seem to be a  like there is a  task.

Does anyone know how to do this?

Thanks,
David

Comment: It would be helpful to see the nant code you are doing for the `exec`

Answer (score 1):

I'm assuming you have the registry settings you want to import in a .reg file.   The default handler for a .reg file in Windows is 'Merge'.

You should be able to just pass the .reg file name as command directly to CCNET exec to import the settings.

Answer (score 0):

You can wrap the windows command REG as in REG QUERY in an exec task?